# Who is the woman from Cush?

Tags: numbers, moses

In Numbers 12 we see that Miriam and Aaron speak against Moses because he married a woman from Cush.

[Numbers 12:1 (ESV)](http://www.esvbible.org/Numbers12.1)

> Miriam and Aaron spoke against Moses because of the Cushite woman whom he had married, for he had married a Cushite woman.

Who is this woman? Is this referring to Zipporah or another wife?

Answer (score 4):

It is not known for certain whether the Cushite woman and Zipporah are one and the same.  Some Rabbinic commentators, including Rashi, point out that this wife is mentioned nowhere else in the Torah.  Therefore, the Cushite woman from Numbers 12:1 must be referring to Zipporah.  Other commentators cite the Chronicles of Moses, which is an early Midrashic source.  The Chronicles say that Moses went to Ethiopia after he fled Egypt to get away from Pharoah.  While in Ethiopia, he married a Cushite woman (not Zipporah).